# Javascript loading but not running - rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, loading

I have in my application layout file an external javascript file witch has several lines of code and at the end runs a function like `BooManager.init()` no big deal...

the problem is, it is not running the inside code on this javascript file.

this is how i use it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    bb_bid = "1615455";
    bb_lang = "en-US";
    bb_keywords = "iphone4s, apple";
    bb_name = "custom";
    bb_limit = "8";
    bb_format = "bbb";
</script>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://widgets.boo-box.com/javascripts/embed.js" %>
```

but it didn`t do anything it was suposed to do...

i`ve tried in simple html file and it works... what am i doing wrong?

NOTE:

the default way in html is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    bb_bid = "1615455";
    bb_lang = "en-US";
    bb_keywords = "keywords, between, commas";
    bb_name = "custom";
    bb_limit = "8";
    bb_format = "bbb";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.boo-box.com/javascripts/embed.js"></script>
```

-- EDIT --

the result generated by rails:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.boo-box.com/javascripts/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: check the resulting 'view source', does it have the script line there?

Comment: edit- added the script line added by rails

Comment: I was able to duplicate your problem in jsfiddle - can definitely see it happening. I'm trying to figure out a solution without slogging through the embed code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not evaluating the script when loading using the `<%=` method. I'm not familiar with that syntax, but from the effect, that's what it sounds like. It's treating the script as html rather than code.

jQuery has a script load function that will get a script dynamically from a URL and then `eval()` it to execute it.

**UPDATED WITH SAMPLE CODE**

Add jQuery to your app:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then use it to load your script:

```
$.getScript('http://widgets.boo-box.com/javascripts/embed.js');
```

**UPDATE NUMBER 2**

I was able to duplicate the problem in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7x2zT/4/

If what you are trying to accomplish is to get your parameters activated before the script shows the widget - the default one looks like a sidebar, whereas your parameters make it more of a banner, then just make sure you put your parameters above the `<script src` stuff.

If you **must** be able to load dynamically, then you're going to have to figure out where the bug lies in the embed code, or if there's some other activation method. That site's documentation doesn't seem to be in English, so I can't help with that.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, how can i do that? i tried getScript but it didn`t do anything not even load the script

Comment: nope... ```ReferenceError: Can't find variable: BooManager`` still can`t use it